# lock text files with passwords

Tags: security, cryptography, locking, text-files, file-locking

Is there any way to protect the text file. I want to protect my text files to protect with password. So how is it possible that when client wants to open the text file it asks for password and files can be opened in notepad only after entering the right password. By using this can be make our files secure

Comment: What have you tried? Which is your traget programming language? And which is your target platform?

Comment: Encrypt it, and use a password to derive the key. But a straight forward implementation wouldn't support opening with notepad, only with a specialized program. Alternatively you can use disk encryption software, such as truecrypt.

Comment: i have to read back the html file using java so decryption will be implemented using java and i am trying to build it for windows.

Comment: If you want to interoperate with existing software like Notepad, you'll need an encrypted file system, like a TrueCrypt volume. This isn't a programming question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zip it and password protect the entry :) full compatibility with any PC and decent security :) (Zip ueses AES to pretect it's entries).