# How to SECURE a txt and cvs file containing leads data from DIRECT ACCESS

Tags: php, html, webforms

I am using a custom Optin form , Coded in html, It has a connected mailing script which emails me the submitted optin data, With the help of this great community , I was able to save the optin data on the server too , In separate .txt and .cvs files BUT when I checked it now , it is available to general public as well and the search engines too. So , I want to make it **PASSWORD PROTECTED** or **Appear EMPTY/UN ACCESSIBLE** for normal users .

I had already blocked search engines with robots.txt.

This is the url of the leads page
http://timesharesgroup.com/sell/index.html
*******************UPDATE***********************

THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE , THE CLOSEST ANSWER I GOT WAS
[lock text files with passwords [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540917/lock-text-files-with-passwords)

I am not looking to make it downloadable , I just want it to be secured from other people so The leads data can be kept to me only and can not be misused.

Comment: THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE , THE CLOSEST ANSWER I GOT WAS lock text files with passwords [closed]

I am not looking to make it downloadable , I just want it to be secured from other people so The leads data can be kept to me only and saved from misuse.

That other question is not anyway duplicated , that has something to do with **documents that logged in users can download. **

Comment: check the question it was actually marked as a duplicate of - It says "secure files for download", but it looks like what you really want is for no-one else to be able to download it but for you to be able to download.

Comment: I do not want it to be downloadable in any mean , I want to view it online when I login to my cpanel right click it and click view, Not when I am not logged in and i goto site.com/dir/name.txt and it shows up. You need to understand the question 1st , Where did I say I want it to download it my self ? I said I do not want it accessable by everyone , that is it, nothing about downloading or related, I want it be viewable only By the cpanel admin when logged in